# Why does the same bash script behave differently on different laptops?

Tags: bash, scripts, printing

I'm running a bash script that doesn't behave the same with different laptops. I'm using HP G7 and Acer Swift 3 both with fresh installs of Ubuntu 19.10, and on HP it works fine, but on Acer it doesn't. This is the script:

```
output=REAL.in

for j in $(seq 1 1 1000)
do
a=$(echo "0.010000 * $j" | bc)

  xx=$(cat epsxx.dat | grep -m1 "$a" |awk -F '[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' '{print $3}')  
  yy=$(cat epsyy.dat | grep -m1 "$a" |awk -F '[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' '{print $3}')  
  zz=$(cat epszz.dat | grep -m1 "$a" |awk -F '[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' '{print $3}')  
  xy=$(cat epsxy.dat | grep -m1 "$a" |awk -F '[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' '{print $3}')  
  yz=$(cat epsyz.dat | grep -m1 "$a" |awk -F '[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' '{print $3}')  
  zx=$(cat epszx.dat | grep -m1 "$a" |awk -F '[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' '{print $3}')  
  echo "  $a   $xx   $yy   $zz   $xy   $yz   $zx" |tee -a $output

done
```

It opens the files that look like this:

```
  # energy grid [eV]     epsr     epsi
       0.010000       3.500795      15.109691  
       0.020000       3.511381       7.527619  
       0.030000       3.705182       5.390616  
       0.040000       3.660826       4.569134  
       0.050000       3.476175       4.169090  
       0.060000       3.229346       3.926634
```

and so on. On HP it does exactly what it's supposed to do, it takes the second column of different files and puts them in the output files by lines. On Acer I only get the first column, the counter.

It used to work on Acer with 19.04, but when I reinstalled it again to 19.04 it stopped working.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Does the laptops have same Ubuntu version?

Comment: Yes, the both have the 19.10. I solved it below.

Answer (score 3):

Please check what AWK you are using.

It can be gawk or mawk, these utilities are working slightly different.

Comment: This was exactly the case. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I guess awk was missing from the system, installing gawk with apt-get solved the problem.

Comment: More likely, `mawk` was installed as the default awk (you'd have seen errors if there was no awk at all)